# Record audio in background

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm wondering if anyone has any idea that **capture audio** from the device's **microphone** on the new **Windows Phone 7** in background (**Silverlight**, not XNA)
or any code to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Even in a Silverlight application, the Microphone is accessed via libraries in the `Microsoft.Xna.*` namespaces.
The use of such namespaces is not supported in a Background Task. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962(v=vs.92)

This is not possible and would break the security principle of not allowing apps to do something that the user isn't aware of.